# Notification sound stopped when notification panel / drawer is shown

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to implement an alarm app where a local notification with sound will pop up when alarmmanager triggers. The notification does show up with the sound when the alarm triggers, but for some reason immediately stops when I open up the notification panel by swiping down. I have tested other alarm apps and they work fine (the sound still plays when the notification is shown in the panel), so it's not because of the system.

Here is the code in my service to trigger the notification

```
     override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
        // create notification
        createNotificationChannel(this)
        var builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Notification title")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.launch_background)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentText("content")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            var notification: Notification = builder.build();
            notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT or Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
            notify(11111, notification)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I end up change my JobIntentService to Service so that I can call startForeground to it and play media in the service.